# how to Bind checkbox in mvc3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

entry in entrylist contains all items which has been selected by checkbox during insert time.

```
@foreach(ddt.models.abc entry in entrylist)
{

<div style="height:auto !important;max-height:160px; overflow-y:auto;width:79%;">

@{
   List<abc.Models.Actor> Actorobjlist = abc.Service.Class1.loaplist();

    }
   @foreach (abc.Models.loap Actorobj in loapobjlist)
   { 
<div class="loap">
  <input type="checkbox" value='@loapobj.Actor1'  name="actorl" />
 <label>@loapobj.Actor1</label>
  </div>
   }

    </div>
}
```

I want to cheked all checkbox items which all items exist in "entry in entrylist" in foreach loop

Comment: can you clarify how you determine the check status of the checkboxes again please?

Comment: if entry.acror1 has value not null then first checkbox should be checked and same as all

Comment: so if entry.actor1.value == loapobj.Actor1, then check it?